# how to find corrupted file from buffer in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

actually i uploaded a file from apolloGraphQl, then i have a file in createReadStream which it's promise.
now i want to make sure this file is image before save it. how to know that file is not corrupted?

this is my node js code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
const FileType = require('file-type');

 let UploadAvatar = async(_ , args) => {

    //save image function
    let saveImage = ({stream, extention}) => {
        const dir = `../public/avatar`;
        const date = `${new Date().getTime()}`;

        mkdirp.sync(path.join(__dirname, `${dir}`));
        const filePath = `${dir}/${date}.${extention}`;

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            stream
                .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, `${filePath}`)))
                .on(`error`,error => reject({error}))
                .on('finish', () => resolve({filePath}))
        })
    }
  
    const {createReadStream, mimetype} = await args.image;
    const stream = createReadStream();
    //get extention 
    const extention = mimetype.split('/').pop();
    //save file
    const { filePath } = await saveImage({ stream, extention});

    console.log(filePath);

} 
module.exports = UploadAvatar;
```

save file work fine. **but i can save corrupted file also!**

Another point I have to mention is this: i upload file by react apollo-upload-client. then args.image variable content:

```
args.image =  {
      filename: 'fileName',
      mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
      encoding: '7bit',
      createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream]
    }
```

this mimetype is not reliable.

Comment: id be using [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) anyway, so loading the buffer then attempting to read the [meta](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-input#metadata) would yield/throw its not a valid image

Comment: can you explain more how can i read meta?

Comment: thanks bro, i resolved it.